# What is the ideal position of placing @Cacheable annotation in service implementation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I want to cache data, but I'm bit confused about the placement of `@Cacheable` annotation in my spring-boot project.

```
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getSampleMethod1() {
        Map<String, String> map = getSampleMethod2();
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    @Cacheable
    public Map<String, String> getSampleMethod2() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Map<String, String> map1 = getSampleMethod3();
        return map1;
    }

    private Map<String, String> getSampleMethod3(){
        Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("name1", "value1");
        map2.put("name2", "value2");
        map2.put("name3", "value3");
        return map2;
    }
```

The above code is not able to cache the data. I'm calling `getSampleMethod1()` from my controller and `getSampleMethod2()` is running every time I hit the API on controller.

Can anyone please help me in understanding the concept of proxy object in caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only call to `getSampleMethod2()` from the external class will be intercepted (actually the calls coming through the proxy). So, in your case, as you are calling from the same class your method call will not be intercepted, hence `@Cacheable` will not work.

If want it to be work you need to create self autowire object of your class and call the method on that object.

```
class MyService{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;      

    MyService self;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        self = applicationContext.getBean(MyService.class);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getSampleMethod1() {
        Map<String, String> map = self.getSampleMethod2();
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @amit but I don't have much idea about `ApplicationContext` class, so, I'm finding difficulty in creating `applicationContext` object. But the problem is solved by simply autowiring `MyService`.

Comment: @DevenderKumar Yes, you can do it by simply auto wiring your `MyService` bean. In my example, you can also get the application context by auto wire it. I have edited my answer. Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried autowiring `ApplicationContext` but there is no `getBean()` method for this class.

Comment: @DevenderKumar I believe you are missing something. There must be a getBean method available on application context. ApplicationContext implements BeanFactory and BeanFactory has getBean(). Please take look on docs :  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-

Comment: Got it, I was using apache `ApplicationContext` class instead of springframework `ApplicationContext` interface.